# Cannot make a static referecnce to the non- static type E

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
import java.util.*;

public class Gen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] name = {"Selva", "KSA", "selva","ksa"};
        List<E> s = new ArrayList<E>(); 
        s.addAll(Arrays.asList(name));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

while Compiling i am getting error like below

> ERROR in Gen.java (at line 6)
>
> ```
>     List<E> s = new ArrayList<E>(); 
>          ^
> ```
>
> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E
>
> ERROR in Gen.java (at line 6)
>
> ```
>   List<E> s = new ArrayList<E>(); 
>                             ^
> ```
>
> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a list of strings, not a list of an undefined, imaginary type E:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or simpler, if you're using Java 7:

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
```

Learn about generics by reading [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 1):

The type `E` does not exist.

Here, `s` is a list of `String` so use: `List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();`

Answer (score 1):

You can make the system infer the type but otherwise no, you cannot use a dynamic type in the static context.

```
public static <T> List<T> makeList(final T... values) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(values));
    return list;
}

public void test() {
    String[] names = {"Selva", "KSA", "selva", "ksa"};
    List<String> s = makeList(names);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: @Selva - in this code you can see that the invocation of `makeList` from `test` passes an array of `String` and expects a `List<String>` in return. The static `makeList` method uses `T` instead of `String` but states that it returns a `List` of the same type as the components of the array. This matches the usage and therefore passes compilation.